# Alter Database open; ERROR

Tags: database, rdbms, ordbms

After mounting the database I tried executing these command- alter database open; emanating from a shutdown initialization error but my oracle kept returning an ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments [dbkif_find_next_record_1], [], [], [].
Please, how do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

ORA-600 is an internal error, and in this case Oracle Support should be contacted.
On the other hand, check the alertlog, and the incident trace for more information.
With the provided info, I can't say anything more.